# Java short name for generic

Tags: java, generics, types

When programming heavily with generics in java, it's common to have many nested generics:

```
 List<MyClass<MyClass2,MyClass3,List<MyClass4<MyClass5>>> my_list= new LinkedList<MyClass<MyClass2,MyClass3,List<MyClass4<MyClass5>>>();
```

While this "works", the readability of the resulting code suffers. Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Would it be possible to define a new "temporary type"?

```
type1= List<MyClass4<MyClass5>>;
type2= MyClass<MyClass2,MyClass3,type1>;
List<type2> my_list= new List<type2>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `typedef` equivalent of C/C++ in Java

Answer (score 3):

You could define new types in the form of (empty) classes:

```
class Type1 extends List<MyClass4<MyClass5>> { }

class Type2 extends MyClass<MyClass2, MyClass3, Type1> { }

List<Type2> my_list= new List<Type2>();
```

Of course you would loose some of the flexibility of generics but maybe you can do this for some commonly used combinations, possibly even as inner classes.

Comment: It is a good solution, however, the only drawback is that `Type1` will not be completely compatible with `List<MyClass4<MyClass5>>` in both directions. `Type1` can be assigned to `List` but not the other way.

Comment: @buc thanks for mentioning that. Same goes for `Type2` which cannot be assgined to `MyClass<MyClass2, MyClass3, Type1>`.

Comment: -1 I don't think this would be very helpful in practice - it would force you to use the `Type1` implementation of `List<MyClass4<MyClass5>>`, whatever that may be, effectively killing parametric polymorphism.

Comment: @PaulBellora I never said it was a good solution, just one that might be working for OP ;-)

Comment: Indeed, this mostly work when you only need the "outer" type, but once you try to access methods of the "inner" generics, everything fails, since you can't cast to the outer type without throwing a ClassCastException